# Using grep to find and edit the correct form

Tags: php, shell, grep

I have a website, built on a CMS (Ushahidi) that has built in translations. At the top right of each page is a drop down for 30+ languages. I'm trying to edit this so that only two languages remain: English and French.

In order to find which files to edit I have been using grep like so:

```
grep -Rl English pathtowebsite
```

I used the word English as a search term. This led me down a rabbit hole of files and directories that hold the language translations for each language option. I deleted all of them except English and French.

But, the form still gives options for all the languages. I am at a loss for what search term to use in order to find the form to edit.

Here is a sample of the html. How would I grep to find this form in order to remove the options for every language except English and French? The website in question is here, if it helps: http://tinyurl.com/c8djrvr

```
<div class="language-box"><form action="https://trashswag.com/main?l=uk_UA&amp;l=en_GB" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="l" value="en_GB"  />
<select id="l" name="l"  onchange="this.form.submit()" >
<option value="az_AZ">Azərbaycan dili (AZ)</option>
<option value="id_ID">Bahasa Indonesia (ID)</option>
<option value="bs_BA">Bosanski (BA)</option>
<option value="ca_ES">Català (ES)</option>
<option value="cy_GB">Cymraeg (GB)</option>
<option value="da">Dansk</option>
<option value="de_DE">Deutsch (DE)</option>
<option value="en_GB" selected="selected">English (GB)</option>
<option value="en_US">English (US)</option>
<option value="es_AR">Español (AR)</option>
<option value="es_CL">Español (CL)</option>
<option value="es_ES">Español (ES)</option>
<option value="es_PE">Español (PE)</option>
</select></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ushahidi framework might provide you cleaner solution but purely talking about grep command you can use:

```
 grep -Rl 'English (.*)</option>' pathtowebsite
```

**Update:**

Actually this drop-down is being dynamically populated instead of coming directly from a file. It is coming directly from `application/cache/kohana_configuration` if you clear your cache directory after tweaking `application/i18n` you should be fine.

Comment: Hi anubhava thanks for responding. Tried that and produced no search results. What does (.*) do?

Comment: In regex dot matches any character so `English (.*)` will match both `English (GB)` and `English (US)`

Comment: I also have `Ushahidi` installed and when I ran above command it did find 2 files in `installer` directory.

Comment: Right, but the installer directory was deleted after installation as per instructions

Comment: Hmm that's right. Then I guess there is no other matching file. It might be possible that this drop-down is being dynamically populated instead of coming directly from a file (sorry I don't know much about internals of Ushahidi)

Comment: I suspect it is coming directly from `application/cache/kohana_configuration` if you clear your cache directory after tweaking `application/i18n` you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the Ushahidi wiki tells us that the language dropdown is generated by looking at the the `application/i18n` directory. You should remove the corresponding folder for the languages you don't want to support from that directory.

Don't forget to clear the application cache by removing the contents of your `application/cache` folder after making the changes.

Wiki page:
https://wiki.ushahidi.com/display/WIKI/Localization

Comment: Thanks for the info Hless. I had already removed all other languages from that directory. I've cleared cache and checked it on 3 different browsers - the options all remain!

Comment: Also, I have tried this before on the previous version of Ushahidi 2.7 (I'm running 2.7.1) and the solution of removing the folders did work.

Comment: So when you said clear the cache I assumed you meant in my browser. Clearing the cache directory solved the problem. Thanks for the info on ln18 directory

Comment: I should have been more concise. But if you followed the directions on the wiki page, it also said to remove the contents of the `application/cache` folder after adding a language. My guess is that this is also the case when deleting languages ;). Anyway, glad to see your problem is solved.